# Google Sheets how to prevent sheet page from being renamed?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I know I can set an entire page to be protected, but is there a way I can just make the name of the page protected?

I have a Apps Script that depends on the sheet name so I don't want anyone to be able to rename it, but others still need to be able to have edit access to everything else on the sheet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that's possible.

But in your script, use the [sheet-id](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getSheetId%28%29) instead, which is unique and unchangeable, unless one deletes and recreates the sheet. In which case you could fallback to its name, or just understandably fail. Something like this:

```js
function getSheetById(id) {
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets();
  for( var i in sheets )
    if( sheets[i].getSheetId() == id )
      return sheets[i];
  throw new Error('Sheet with id "'+id+'" not found.');
}
```

Then parametrize and use this `getSheetById` function instead of using their names. You can see a sheet id by selecting it and looking at your browser's location bar. It's the last '#gid=' part. You can confirm it in code using:

```js
function logId() {
  Logger.log(SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getSheetId());
  //click View > Logs
}
```